# Hosts redirect for HTTPS sites?

Tags: windows, ssl, hosts

I'm trying to do some DIY parental controls on my Windows box that redirects certain sites, like YouTube, to localhost. It technically works and redirects, but fails to load the localhost site because the SSL cert doesn't actually serve that name.

Is there any way to make this work? I assume the answer is no, because security, but figured I'd ask.

Comment: There are excellent parental controls built into Windows 10, no need for DIY.

Comment: They're ok, but not really what I want. For starters, it requires a separate family account be set up for the child, and I want to block machine-wide. Also it only applies to Edge/IE not across the board.

More important though is I'm trying to be funny and display a Nedry GIF when accessing a blocked site. It works fine for HTTP sites, for HTTPs it gives me the cert error. So its successful in blocking, just not in being fun.

Comment: I thought that maybe using `netsh` to redirect traffic from 443 to 80 might help but it doesn't seem to. i.e using `netsh int portproxy` to set up the 127.0.0.1 redirection from port to port but I couldn't get it to redirect https to a local IIS.  Not quite what you're after but I think the Sophos Home free edition has web control and you can manage it via a web UI.